# Laravel AD LDAP sometimes return null for email?

Tags: php, ldap

Just wondering if anyone else has had this problem and maybe suggestions where to look to troubleshoot.

I created a laravel application with ADLDAP2 addon. It authenticates against AD, and had work for awhile now. The application would grab username, email, etc, when it created the accounts for Laravel end. Our organization uses a uniform account ID, say A1234567@ etc.

Besides the main accounts, we have new users being imported from another service into AD with the different format B123456 etc. The application authenticates successfully with new B accounts but doesn't import/sync the assocaited email address. A accounts import everything, B imports the name, username, password as required but no email, even though there is an email in AD.

Would this be an AD related issue with new accounts? or would this be configuration with my laravel adldap install. I am currently running v3 of the adldap2 module.